# Excel - Combine 2 sheets into 1 based on person ID and creating new rows if ID is found more than once

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have person data and address data in 2 different sheets which I wish to combine into 1. The problem is that each person can have more than 1 address.

For example, if i have the following 2 datasets:

```
**Person Data**
PersonID         Name

1          John Smith
2          Mark Brown

**Address Data**
PersonID      Address

1                  UK
1              France
1                 USA
2                  UK
```

I need them to be joined as such:

```
**Combined Data**
PersonID      Name       Address

1       John Smith            UK
1       John Smith        France
1       John Smith           USA
2       Mark Brown            UK
```

Is there any way to do this through excel formulas? Thanks

Comment: If things are more complicated than what you show, you can easily use Power Query to join the two tables

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you simply want to add the person's name to each row of the address data list. If so, this is easy.

#### Asumptions

- Person data is sorted and consecutive (i.e. PersonID 1 is located in row 2, PersonID 100 is located in row 101) — if this is not true see last section.
- Address data is sorted

#### Solution

```
**Combined Data Sheet**
PersonID          Name                            Address
=$Addresses!A2    =OFFSET($Names!$B$1, A2, 0)     =$Addresses!B2
```

And copy the formulas downwards of course.

#### Explanation

The first and last columns simply are copied out of the Addresses sheet. The `OFFSET` function allows you to go downwards or across by a certain amount. In this case, we know that the correct Person will be on the row of PersonID + 1. Since we start on row 1 (`$Names!$B$1`) the +1 is unnecessary.

#### Non-consecutive Person IDs

The `VLOOKUP` function can be used to search for a PersonID and then return another column in the same row. In this case, something like:

```
=VLOOKUP(A2, Names!$A$1:$B$1000, 2, FALSE)
```